# Error compiling pre-generated view in VS 2008

Tags: entity-framework, visual-studio-2008, linq-to-entities

I am created pre-generated views for my EDMX using VS 2008, .NET 3.5 and Entity framework.

I have generated using the t4 templates mentioned [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2008/06/20/how-to-use-a-t4-template-for-view-generation.aspx) and got my mymodel.views.cs file. It's around 40 mb is size.

Added the views.cs file to my web application and my web service. When i build the apps, the webservice would build without any error and i can get the WS to work. But, the build fails in the website with the error

> error CS0234: The type or namespace
>   name 'Mapping' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'System.Data' (are you
>   missing an assembly reference?)

The System.Data assembly is referenced in both the projects and the version denotes .NET 2.0. Suspect something trivial i am missing here, but still clueless.

Any pointers would help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a reference to `System.Data.Entity.dll`, which contains the [System.Data.Mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.mapping.aspx) namespace.